# Export name cannot be found

Tags: reactjs, export

I try to set the condition for my VideoChat then export it to App.js but my app cannot render. I got the error "**export 'VideoChat' (imported as 'VideoChat') was not found in './VideoChat' (possible exports: default)**". Is there anything wrong with my export and import name? please help me! Thank yu so much!

App.js":

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import VideoChat from "./VideoChat";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <header>
        <h1> Video Chat with Hooks </h1>{" "}
      </header>{" "}
      <main>
        <VideoChat />
      </main>{" "}
      <footer>
        <p>
          Made with by <a href="https://twitter.com/philnash"> philnash </a>{" "}
        </p>{" "}
      </footer>{" "}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

VideoChat.js:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import Lobby from "./Lobby";

function VideoChat() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [roomName, setRoomName] = useState("");
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

  const handleUsernameChange = useCallback((event) => {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
  }, []);

  const handleRoomNameChange = useCallback((event) => {
    setRoomName(event.target.value);
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(
    async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const data = await fetch("/video/token", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          identity: username,
          room: roomName,
        }),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }).then((res) => res.json());
      setToken(data.token);
    },
    [username, roomName]
  );

  const handleLogout = useCallback((event) => {
    setToken(null);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      if (token){" "}
      {
        <div>
          <p> Username: {username} </p> <p> Room name: {roomName} </p>{" "}
          <p> Token: {token} </p>{" "}
        </div>
      }{" "}
      else{" "}
      {
        <Lobby
          username={username}
          roomName={roomName}
          handleUsernameChange={handleUsernameChange}
          handleRoomNameChange={handleRoomNameChange}
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
        />
      }{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
export default VideoChat;
```

Lobby.js:

```
import React from "react";

const Lobby = ({
  username,
  handleUsernameChange,
  roomName,
  handleRoomNameChange,
  handleSubmit,
}) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <h2> Enter a room </h2>{" "}
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="name"> Name: </label>{" "}
        <input
          type="text"
          id="field"
          value={username}
          onChange={handleUsernameChange}
          required
        />
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="room"> Room name: </label>{" "}
        <input
          type="text"
          id="room"
          value={roomName}
          onChange={handleRoomNameChange}
          required
        />
      </div>{" "}
      <button type="submit"> Submit </button>{" "}
    </form>
  );
};

export default Lobby;
```

Comment: change it to ```const VideoChat = () => {``` and rename fileName to index.js if your file is in VideoChat folder